# Untagged frame and VLAN-based Carrier Ethernet Service (eg EVP-LAN)

Tags: evc

When sending an untagged frame over a VLAN-based Carrier Ethernet service (eg EVP-LAN), it requires a CE-VLAN ID (1-4094). Does it mean that an untagged frame becomes a tagged frame, or, an untagged frame is simply mapped to the EVC in untagged form?

Comment: There's no general rule - you'd need to ask your carrier.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks not under your direct control are off-topic here. You need to ask the carrier how it has configured its network.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means an untagged frame will be **discarded**.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. MEF standards (101.3) do allow transmission of untagged frames over a virtual private EVC. I was only asking the mechanism, how it is done.